# Clone new layer

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV container. I need to overlay it with another semi-transparent layer. So, the way I thought I could do it is via several steps:

1. clone initial element
2. remove children from the cloned element
3. apply semi-transparency to the clone
4. get position of the initial element
5. position clone

Here's my code:

```
$('.myEm').clone().empty().addClass('semi').height(initEmHeight).insertAfter(this).css({ 'top' : pos.top + 'px', 'left' : pos.left + 'px', 'z-index' : '99'});
```

It works until I start adding CSS. What am I missing?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without the rest of the related code. Can you provide a snippet with the HTML, and with the JavaScript where the `initEmHeight` and `pos` variables are getting set?

Comment: [Your code works fine in theory](http://jsfiddle.net/08mhgw0m/). Then again, I have no idea if I'm even close at guessing what your implementation is.

Comment: Presumably `pos` exists and is in scope?

Comment: Yes I get position of the original em.

Comment: Ahh, I think I found my problem. For some reason as soon as I added position, the cloned element collapsed to 1px wide. I need to add the width as well. Also I am able to position with FIXED but it stays in place even when I scroll the page. I believe I need to use position: relative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an overlay using CSS pseudo element as shown below, no need to clone or position things manually. For example :

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass("overlay");
    alert("click");
});
```

```css
#content {
   position: relative;
   width: 150px;
   height: 100px;
   background: dodgerblue;
 }
 #content.overlay::after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
    <button>click!</button>
</div>
```

You can control the overlay by adding and removing the class `overlay` from `#content`.

Comment: I'm afraid this will work only if I could specify the exact coordinates. My element can be anywhere on a page generated dynamically.

Comment: @santa If the element is positioned (*other than static*) it'll work. The `0` coordinates is the coordinates of your content, not the window. The overlay will be stretched to fill it, no matter what the size of content is. Give it a try...

Comment: I really like it. But in my case the layover is a localized version of the modal layover layer, that covers other elements and prevents from clicking, for example. I believe this will style properly but will still leave other elements, like links and buttons withing the original element accessible.

Comment: @santa this will cover the elements and prevent it from clicking, as you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y9g9pyze/). I can't help you any further unless you improve the question with sample code or an online demo... BTW If if you like it, then you can upvote it because as far as I can see it does answer the question above ;)

Comment: Sorry, I tested in FF and I am still able to click a link and a button: http://jsfiddle.net/y9g9pyze/1/

Comment: @santa I just tested in latest version of Chrome, FF, Opera and safari 5.1.7  and it's not clickable after the overlay is added by clicking the button once...